# checkbox and input field correlation in knockout

Tags: html, knockout.js

**Description:**

I have two things, a checkbox and input field. Here's what I want. In my viewmodel, I have two observables, one which saves the check box check/uncheck(ture or false), and another, which saves the input field value. Both of these values come from the database, but I have them as static here to simplify things. So, when the page loads and if the checkbox value is true, the input field should be enabled and it should display the value.The checkbox should also be displayed as checked. If the checkbox is then uncheked, the input field value should be zero and the input field should be disabled. If the checkbox is then checked after unchecking, the input field value should still be zero.

**Fiddle:**

```
 data-bind="checked: boxChecked" type="checkbox" ></input>
     <br/>
  Result:
  <input data-bind="enable: boxChecked() == true,
                         value: boxCheked() = true ? result : result = 0" type="text"></input>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KGSUD/1/

I have been playing around with the fiddle for quite some time but couldnt figure it out.

I will appreciate your help folks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take the logic out of the view (HTML) and put it in the ViewModel.

Html:

```
<input data-bind="checked: boxChecked" type="checkbox" ></input>
<br/>
Result:
<input data-bind="enable: boxChecked, value: result" type="text"></input>
```

JS:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.boxChecked = ko.observable(true);
    self.result = ko.observable('10');

    self.boxChecked.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        if (!newValue)
            self.result("0");
    });
};
```

The subscription will take of setting the `result`, the html bindings become simpler. Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/yyhGa/)

Comment: Is there a way to make the value zero when the check box is unchecked upon page load? And why can't I do it in view? I mean, will it not work?

Comment: Yes, you could enforce that in the viewmodel constructor. Also, you can put anything wherever you want (as long as it works), but using knockout with the MVVM pattern is generally recommended, and will (generally) result in more reusable code. Business logic like *setting a viewmodel property to a specific value based on some condition* in the view goes against the MVVM pattern, as business logic belongs in the viewmodel. Only logic related to how to display information should ever be in the view. But as always, exceptions exist, use your judgement, etc.

Comment: thanks. I actually implementes your solution, and I am getting checkbox as checked no matter if the value is true or false. Dont know how to solve that. I am sure it has nothing to do with your solution since your example works fine.

Comment: by the way, where is newValue initialized?

Comment: `newValue` is just the parameter name for the subscription function. Knockout passes the value of the "observed" subscribee to the function as the first parameter; you could name it anything you wanted to.